# Android paint issue on different API

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I am having issues working with Paint for different API's for Android.

The user is supposed to be able to draw letters on an area, which works fine on API 8 and 10, but for API 16 and 17, the lines look very different. I will show using images.

This is how it's supposed to look, [API 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyAKA.png).

This is how it looks on [API 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDlqR.png).

**Here is my code for the draw view:**

```
public class TouchDrawView extends View
{
    private Paint mPaint;
    private ArrayList<Point> mPoints;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> mStrokes;

    public TouchDrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        mPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
        mStrokes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
        mPaint = createPaint(Color.BLACK, 14);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        super.onDraw(c);

        for(ArrayList<Point> points: mStrokes)
        {
            drawStroke(points, c);
        }

        drawStroke(mPoints, c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            mPoints.add(new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));

            this.invalidate();
        }

        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            mStrokes.add(mPoints);
            mPoints = new ArrayList();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void drawStroke(ArrayList stroke, Canvas c)
    {
        if (stroke.size() > 0)
        {
            Point p0 = (Point)stroke.get(0);

            for (int i = 1; i < stroke.size(); i++)
            {
                Point p1 = (Point)stroke.get(i);
                c.drawLine(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x, p1.y, mPaint);
                p0 = p1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        mPoints.clear();
        mStrokes.clear();

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private Paint createPaint(int color, float width)
    {
        Paint temp = new Paint();
        temp.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        temp.setAntiAlias(true);
        temp.setColor(color);
        temp.setStrokeWidth(width);
        temp.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have up-voted your question in the hopes that someone will be able to give you an answer to it.  Good luck and great first post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it seems your app is hardware accelerated and in this mode some features like `setStrokeCap()` (for lines) are not supported, Have a look: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported

Just disable hardware acceleration and try again. This is how you disable it:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

Comment: Ugh, no. That is the wrong way to turn off hardware acceleration. You should just turn it off selectively for the impacted layer (`View`), so that hardware acceleration is still used everywhere else. Use `setLayerType`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType